# Variable is used without being initiallized

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have

```
run(){
...
struct sockaddr_in from;
int i = recvpacket(buffer,from, fromlen)
...
}


recvpacket(char *buffer, struct sockaddr_in from, int fromlen)
{
//udp recvfrom stores the address of the sender in from
}
```

I get the following runtime Error in VC++

```
runtime check failure - the variable 'from' is used without being initialized
```

should I pass by reference, how should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things to fix:

- to remove the warning you have to initialize `from` like this for example:

  `struct sockaddr_in from= {0};`
- to get the address when calling `recvpacket` you have to declare it as by reference

  `recvpacket(char *buffer, struct sockaddr_in& from, int fromlen)`

Answer (score 1):

In your run() method: `struct sockaddr_in from = {0};` and pass it by reference to be updated in called method

Comment: @icepack What isn't C/C++? The assignment? Or the null? OK, null was meant to be 0 here.

Comment: That too. The principal difference is lack of {} around 0.